# Why console.log is logged more than once when It should have logged only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest

I was reading through the `The Complete Book on AngularJS, Ari Lerner` book and there I found [this example](http://jsbin.com/qenawifexa/edit?html,js,console,output) on ng-class. I added one extra console.log inside `generateNumber()` function. I see that it was just logged once.

After that I replaced places where `x` was used with `generateNumber()` function call. My code looks something like this after my changes [see this](http://jsbin.com/cazekezexe/1/edit?html,js,console,output):

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/4.3.2/css/foundation.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="LotteryController">
  <div ng-class="{red: generateNumber() > 5}">
    You won!
  </div> 
  <button ng-click="generateNumber()">Draw Number</button>
  <p>Number is: {{ x }}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('LotteryController', function($scope) {
  $scope.generateNumber = function() {
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
    console.log("Number: "+num);
    $scope.x = num;
    return num;
  };
});
```

So I am not able to understand why the `console.log()` was logged that many times and even when I click the button It should have logged only once But It was logged more than once. I am not able understand why that method is called that many times. Also sometime I get this exception (I have pasted only top two lines)

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:
```

what is this $digest for? and why it reached its limit. what is watcher? and please say why logging is done that many times?
Thank you guys,

**EDIT**

Thanks for the response guys, But I want to use something like `ng-class="{red: generateNumber() > 5}"` What is wrong in doing like this. can someone explain me this. I dont want to use `$scope.x` there, so you guys can ignore that for now.

Thank you guys,

Comment: I think you want to change `ng-class` statement to  this one: `ng-class="{red: x > 5}"` since `$scope.x` is already there and you don't need to call that generate function

Comment: I want to call that method from `ng-class` directly. You try to remove the $scope.x from the method and run the program again It logs the many times. [see this](http://jsbin.com/viqaqaseba/1/edit?html,js,console,output). yes I think what you are saying will work But I want to know why can't we call the method directly then. what is wrong in that. and why the logging is done so many time.

Comment: @govindpatel, I explained in my answer.

Comment: @govindpatel, see my updated answer for how to solve the problem without using `$scope.x` in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest):

> Processes all of the watchers of the current scope and its children.
>   Because a watcher's listener can change the model, the $digest() keeps
>   calling the watchers until no more listeners are firing. This means
>   that it is possible to get into an infinite loop. This function will
>   throw 'Maximum iteration limit exceeded.' if the number of iterations
>   exceeds 10.

In other words, ***$digest*** is the process through which your view gets synchronised with your $scope. After the ***digest*** starts, it loops until the state of the `$scope` does not change compared its state in the immediate past cycle.

Changes in the state of the scope are determined by evaluating ***watch*** expressions (explicitly defined, or implied in your view). If each expression evaluates to the same outcome within successive cycles, then the digest will end.

To address your observation specifically, `generateNumber()` always returns a new number! So the ***$digest*** process always saw the scope's state as changed at the end of each cycle. After going through 10 cycles, the system guessed that it's in an infinite loop, so it threw the exception as you observed (and as specified in the doc).

You can solve the problem by following this approach:

```
$scope.generateNumber = function () {
    $scope.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    console.log("Number: " + $scope.x);
};
```

Next the following changes should be made to your markup:

```
  <div ng-class="{red: x > 5}">
    You won!
  </div>
```

As I read you stating in one of your comments "*I don't want to use, x, directly*"; then it would suffice to create a method that returns the class map object instead, or to directly add the class map object to the scope, or add a method that returns the generated number to the scope.

### 1. Add a method that returns the generated number to the scope

JS:

```
var number;
$scope.getNumber = function () {
    return number;
};
$scope.generateNumber = function () {
    $scope.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    number = $scope.x;
    console.log("Number: " + $scope.x);
};
```

HTML

```
  <div ng-class="getNumber() > 5">
    You won!
  </div>
```

### 2. Using a method that returns the class map object

JS:

```
var classMap = {};
$scope.getClassMap = function () {
    classMap.red = $scope.x > 5;
    return classMap;
};
```

HTML

```
  <div ng-class="getClassMap()">
    You won!
  </div>
```

### 3. Directly add the class map object to the scope

JS:

```
$scope.classMap = {};
$scope.generateNumber = function () {
    $scope.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    $scope.classMap.red = $scope.x > 5;
    console.log("Number: " + $scope.x);
};
```

HTML

```
  <div ng-class="classMap">
    You won!
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be that ng-class is verified at each digest, and you call a method so it get called in a loop.

To correct that : add your x to a scope variable and then call generate number to init your x

**HTML : **

```
<div ng-controller="LotteryController">
  <div ng-class="{'red': x > 5}" ng-init="generateNumber()">
    You won!
  </div> 
  <button ng-click="generateNumber()">Draw Number</button>
  <p>Number is: {{ x }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've explained it to you in my answer, ng-class is verified at each digest cycle, and you call a method in it which is triggering another digest cycle, and here comes the loop giving you : 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! You just cannot put a method here, why don't you want to bind the result to a variable ? Try to give an explaination not just that you don't want

Answer (score 1):

console.log is called at each $scope.$digest because you use the method $scope.generateNumber as condition to ng-class, internally generateNumber() modifies the $scope.x variable causing new $digest cycle to run.

at each $digest cycle generate number is called to determine wheather or not to apply the class.

use $scope.x as condition to ng-class

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('LotteryController', function($scope) {
  $scope.generateNumber = function() {
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
    console.log("Number: "+num);
    $scope.x = num;
    return num;
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/4.3.2/css/foundation.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="LotteryController">
  <div ng-class="{red: x > 5}">
    You won!
  </div> 
  <button ng-click="generateNumber()">Draw Number</button>
  <p>Number is: {{ x }}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are calling generateNumber() twise in ng-class and in ng-click that's the reason its logging multiple time. Check it out the change in ng-class:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('LotteryController', function($scope) {
  $scope.generateNumber = function() {
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
    console.log("Number: "+num);
    $scope.x = num;
    return num;
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/4.3.2/css/foundation.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="LotteryController">
  <div ng-class="{red: x > 5}">
    You won!
  </div> 
  <button ng-click="generateNumber()">Draw Number</button>
  <p>Number is: {{ x }}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no I dont want to use the `x` directly in `ng-class`. I want to call the method directly from ng-class. can you see the my comment and @k102 comment.Actually he said the same thing.